# Can you repeat a CSS grid with set (24) columns horizontally?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I feel like this is a stupid question but I want to check there's no way around this.

If you have a 24 column grid with products in a row. Once full, is it possible to make that grid overflow so it goes off the side of the page to scroll horizontally. My assumption is no as the grid is 'fixed' but I wondered if there was a way to repeat the grid horizontally. The reason for this is just to keep all the cards aligned to the other grids on the rest of the page.

The layout I'm after I have built in the following example using 'old skool' percentages. So in short, wondering if I can achieve that with a CSS Grid

https://jsfiddle.net/d2zL5pen/1/

On my attempt with the CSS Grid, which is the included code example below. You'll need to view wider than 800px as I've included mobile fallback.

The obvious problem is that as soon as you add an item that doesn't fit in the remaining space it just gets squeezed in the last column(s). The only way I could possibility see this working is if every 3 items were wrapped in a div, so essentially their own grid.

```css
/* Base */

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Mobile Grid */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  column-gap: 16px;
  margin: 0 -32px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  scroll-padding-left: 32px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Tablet */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  
  .grid__item {
    width: calc(50% - (16px / 2));
  }
}

/* Wide */

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;  
    column-gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
  }
  
  .grid__item {
    width: auto;
  }
  
  .grid__item:nth-child(4n-7) {
    grid-column: 2 / span 6;
  }
  
  .grid__item:nth-child(4n-6) {
    grid-column: 9 / span 8;
  }
  
  .grid__item:nth-child(4n-5) {
    grid-column: 18 / span 5;
  }
  
  .grid__item:nth-child(4n-4) {
    grid-column: 24 / span 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't define a fixed grid and fixed position. Update your grid like below:

```css
  .grid {
    --n: 3;   /* the number of visible column */
    --g: 16px; /* the gap */
    display: grid;
    gap: var(--g);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: calc((100% - (var(--n) - 1)*var(--g))/var(--n));
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

I just wrote an article explaining the above code: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/modern-layouts-using-css-grid

Full code

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Mobile Grid */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  column-gap: 16px;
  margin: 0 -32px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  scroll-padding-left: 32px;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Tablet */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid__item {
    width: calc(50% - (16px / 2));
  }
}

/* Wide */

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
    --n: 3;   /* the number of visible column */
    --g: 16px; /* the gap */
    display: grid;
    gap: var(--g);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: calc((100% - (var(--n) - 1)*var(--g))/var(--n));
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .grid__item {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15031202/pexels-photo-15031202/free-photo-of-canoe-on-lake-in-mountains.jpeg">
    <h3>Product Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way of using a grid in future. I suppose I might struggle with this application in my example as the first 4 columns are different widths (and then repeat those 4 widths again and again)? But great for more standard grid layouts